# "Accessing the Client Using JNLP API" example, error: FailedDownload Exception, when deployed on GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, jnlp

I'm trying to deploy the "texteditor-applet" example on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/usingJNLPAPI.html on Glassfish.

I made TextApplet.war, it deploys fine, but when accessed on my localhost I get this error:

FialedDownload Exception Unable to load resource:

```
http://localhost:8080/TextApplet/applet_JNLP_API.jar
```

GlassFish is running fine, this is the TextApplet.war structure:

```
-index.html
-texteditor-applet(JNLP): archive
-WEB-INF:
|--web.xml
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Text Editor Applet Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> 
    A browser with JavaScript enabled is required for this page to operate properly.
    </noscript>

    <h1>Text Editor Applet Demo</h1>
    <p>Click the Open button and open a plain text file.</p>
    <p>Edit the text and click the Save button</p>
    <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var attributes = { code:'TextEditorApplet.class', archive:'applet_JNLP_API.jar',  width:500, height:300} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'texteditor-applet.jnlp'} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I even tried this: notice the difference at:

```
var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'http://localhost:8080/TextApplet/texteditor-applet.jnlp'} ;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Text Editor Applet Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> 
    A browser with JavaScript enabled is required for this page to operate properly.
    </noscript>

    <h1>Text Editor Applet Demo</h1>
    <p>Click the Open button and open a plain text file.</p>
    <p>Edit the text and click the Save button</p>
    <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script> 
        var attributes = { code:'TextEditorApplet.class', archive:'applet_JNLP_API.jar',  width:500, height:300} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'http://localhost:8080/TextApplet/texteditor-applet.jnlp'} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting that error?  Maybe something wrong with web.xml, I don't know just guessing.

Comment: What is the content of `http://localhost:8080/TextApplet/texteditor-applet.jnlp`?  Make sure to validate it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: The texteditor-applet.jnlp i used was downloaded from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/examplesIndex.html#AppletJNLPAPI so i am not sure if something wrong with it. I'm trying to access JanELa website but it won't work, maybe my connection is not well at the moment, I'll try it latter. Any other suggestions?

Comment: www.pscode.org/janela/ is down at the moment, couldn't access it.

Comment: *"down at the moment"*  My apologies, I am looking into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem. Looks like "applet_JNLP_API.jar" is missing from the package downloaded from this linke: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/examplesIndex.html#AppletJNLPAPI

I found it here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/examples/dist/applet_JNLP_API/AppletPage.html

added it to my project and works fine, Thank You.

Comment: Thank you sir Andrew. will do :)